# In WPF how to get binding of a specific item from the code?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

The example of this would be:

A textBox is bound to some data. There is a second text box which is not bind to anything. So I want to bind text box 2 to the same data 1st textBox is bound.

In other words I wan't to know if the DependencyObject stores some reference to it's data-bindings? If not, what is the way to find out all data-bindings of a specific object?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Try this

Xaml

```
<TextBox Name="textBox1" Text="{Binding Text1}"/>
<TextBox Name="textBox2" Text="No Binding"/>
```

Then we can set the binding of the TextProperty for textBox2 to the same as textBox1 with this code behind

```
BindingExpression bindingExpression = textBox1.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
Binding parentBinding = bindingExpression.ParentBinding;
textBox2.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, parentBinding);
```

Comment: Thanks! That's what I have been looking for!

Comment: What to do if I have nested properies such as `TranslateTransform.XProperty`?

Comment: Why does it have to be `bindingExpression.ParentBinding`?

Answer (score 16):

You can get the binding of any dependency object using

```
System.Windows.Data.BindingOperations.GetBinding(DependencyObject target,DependencyProperty dp)
```

then set the binding with

```
System.Windows.FrameworkElement.SetBinding(DependencyProperty dp, string path)
```

For example:

```
var binding = BindingOperations.GetBinding(textBox1,TextBox.TextProperty);
textBox2.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, binding);
```

Comment: I believe this is a better answer than the accepted one as it doesn't require deconstructing the binding expression. Here you get right to the binding itself.

Answer (score 3):

I know there's already an accepted answer, but is there some reason you're just not doing this?

```
<TextBox Name="textBox1" Text="{Binding Text1}"/>
<TextBox Name="textBox2" Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=textBox1}"/>
```

Now whatever `textBox1` is bound to, even if that binding changes, `textBox2` is as well, no code-behind needed.

Granted I'm basing this on the XAML as presented, and you very well may need the binding itself from code for something else, but if not, the above works just fine.

Answer (score -2):

You can do this in code by calling the `SetBinding` method.

Comment: I know how to set Binding I don't know how to get the reference to an existing binding.

Comment: I have looked in DependencyObject, it doesn't contain any reference to binding source, so I want to know where I can get this reference from.

Comment: Please provide more info or examples how to achieve this

Comment: The answer of @Felipe Faria above is providing some examples.