# Is there a way to get the DataContext for a bound Property

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

Is there a way in code to get the the DataContent for the Text Property of the ComboBox defined below?

```
    <ComboBox Height="21" Text="{Binding Path=Field1.Value}">
        <ComboBox.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Field2.Value}" Value="">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ComboBox.Resources>
    </ComboBox>
```

Currently the DataContext of the ComboBox is the user control in which it lives. Which makes sense because I want my Text bound to one property and my DataTrigger to be bound to another property. But I need to get the DataContext that's being bound to for the Text property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
Binding binding = BindingOperations.GetBinding(yourComboBox, ComboBox.TextProperty);
object theDataContext = binding.Source;
```

Comment: Yes that did it. Here's another answer that I couldn't find earlier. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051360/in-wpf-how-to-get-binding-of-a-specific-item-from-the-code)