# Getting binding of transform property from code behind

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, code-behind

I have code below inside `Grid`:

```
<Grid.RenderTransform>
    <TranslateTransform
        X="{Binding X, Converter={StaticResource HorizontalPositionConverter}}"
        Y="{Binding Y, Converter={StaticResource VerticalPositionConverter}}"
    />
</Grid.RenderTransform>
```

How can I get binding of `TranslateTransform.X` or `TranslateTransform.Y` in code behind? I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051360/in-wpf-how-to-get-binding-of-a-specific-item-from-the-code) question but solution works for non-nested dependency properties. What to do when they are? I cannot consider binding to entire `RenderTransform`. I am developing winrt app, so multibinding is out of the game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code behind binding. I didn't use a converter because my X and Y are defined double. In order to make a correct binding you have to use dependecy property or another notification mechanism (like INotifyPropertyChanged implementation). Here is code behind binding solution (not MVVM). I've added the button to test the moving.
 1. XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="TransformBindingSoHelpAttempt.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" x:Name="This">
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Grid.RenderTransform>
        <TranslateTransform
            X="{Binding ElementName=This, Path=X, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
            Y="{Binding ElementName=This, Path=Y, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </Grid.RenderTransform>
    <Button Content="Click" Width="100" Height="100" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"></Button>
</Grid>
```

2. Code behind :

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty XProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "X", typeof (double), typeof (MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(default(double)));

    public double X
    {
        get { return (double) GetValue(XProperty); }
        set { SetValue(XProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty YProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Y", typeof (double), typeof (MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(default(double)));

    private static double _position;

    public double Y
    {
        get { return (double) GetValue(YProperty); }
        set { SetValue(YProperty, value); }
    }

    private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        X = ++_position;
        Y = _position;
    }
}
```

**Update 1:**
Here is code-behind based solution, **there is no binding in XAML**:
 3. Code behind:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }



    public static readonly DependencyProperty XProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "X", typeof (double), typeof (MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(default(double)));

    public double X
    {
        get { return (double) GetValue(XProperty); }
        set { SetValue(XProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty YProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Y", typeof (double), typeof (MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(default(double)));

    private static double _position;

    public double Y
    {
        get { return (double) GetValue(YProperty); }
        set { SetValue(YProperty, value); }
    }

    private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        X = ++_position;
        Y = _position;
    }

    private void FrameworkElement_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var grid = sender as Grid;
        if(grid == null) return;
        var transform = grid.RenderTransform as TranslateTransform;
        if (transform == null)
        {
            transform = InitTransformBinding();
            grid.RenderTransform = transform;
        }
        else
        {
            InitTransformBinding(transform);
        }

    }

    private TranslateTransform InitTransformBinding(TranslateTransform t = null)
    {

        var transform = t ?? new TranslateTransform();
        var xBinding = new Binding();
        xBinding.Source = this;
        xBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("X");
        xBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
        xBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(transform, TranslateTransform.XProperty, xBinding);
        var yBinding = new Binding();
        yBinding.Source = this;
        yBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("Y");
        yBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
        yBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(transform, TranslateTransform.YProperty, yBinding);
        return transform;
    }
}
```

4. XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="TransformBindingSoHelpAttempt.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" x:Name="This">
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Loaded="FrameworkElement_OnLoaded">
    <Button Content="Click" Width="100" Height="100" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"></Button>
</Grid>
```

**Update 2**, here on each button click you will scale the grid.
 5. Xaml code:

```
Window x:Class="TransformBindingSoHelpAttempt.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:transformBindingSoHelpAttempt="clr-namespace:TransformBindingSoHelpAttempt"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" x:Name="This">
<Window.DataContext>
    <transformBindingSoHelpAttempt:MainViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type transformBindingSoHelpAttempt:ItemDataContext}">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RenderTransform>
                                    <ScaleTransform
                                            ScaleX="{Binding X, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                            ScaleY="{Binding Y, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                                </Grid.RenderTransform>
                                <Button Content="{Binding ButtonContent}" Command="{Binding ButtonCommand}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

6. View models:

```
    public class MainViewModel:BaseObservableObject
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<ItemDataContext>(new List<ItemDataContext>
        {
            new ItemDataContext{ButtonContent = "A", X = 1.0, Y = 1.0},
            new ItemDataContext{ButtonContent = "B", X = 1.0, Y = 1.0},
            new ItemDataContext{ButtonContent = "C", X = 1.0, Y = 1.0},
            new ItemDataContext{ButtonContent = "D", X = 1.0, Y = 1.0},
        });
    }
    public ObservableCollection<ItemDataContext> Items { get; set; }
}

public class ItemDataContext:BaseObservableObject
{
    private ICommand _buttonCommand;
    private object _buttonContent;
    private double _x;
    private double _y;

    public double X
    {
        get { return _x; }
        set
        {
            _x = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public double Y
    {
        get { return _y; }
        set
        {
            _y = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ICommand ButtonCommand
    {
        get { return _buttonCommand ?? (_buttonCommand = new DelegateCommand(Target)); }
    }

    public object ButtonContent
    {
        get { return _buttonContent; }
        set
        {
            _buttonContent = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private void Target(object obj)
    {
        X += 0.2;
        Y += 0.2;
    }
}
```

7. How it is looks like:
[image: running view]

Please keep in mind that the last update solution is based on LayouTransform and re-build the view on each button click (makes it to be scaled). 
Regards,

Comment: Ok, good point. But my task is a bit much difficult I thought, because my `Grid` is embedded inside a list (`ItemsControl`). I didn't provide this info in my question, because I didn't thought it might be important. Could you have any ideas how can I modify your solution for this case?

Comment: @pt12lol why is that important? has each grid its own X and Y positions?do you have a view model?

Comment: My `ItemsControl` has its own view model consisting of many `Grid`'s view models containing relative `X` and `Y` coordinates. Code behind should scale them by `ItemsControl`'s size, because it is UI logic. Grids are just Grids - they don't have `X` and `Y` dependency properties. Putting `Grid` as `UserControl` is impossible for some reasons.

Comment: @pt12lol I can understand that you need move grids by X and Y coordinates from view model of each ItemsControl's item. Is it correct?

Comment: Yup. And then I want to scale `X` and `Y` in code behind. And I don't mind having them in code behind. But I don't have idea how.

Comment: @pt12lol I can think about some approach where the X and Y which are defined in view model can scale the grid? I mean there is a solution where the X and Y coordinates of grid translate transform are under the control of view model. Is it good for your solution?

Comment: I am not positive I understand you correctly, but sounds not bad. I need see some code.