# Programmatically create a checkbox binding for a WPF form

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, data-binding, devexpress

I need to programmatically create a binding for a checkbox that resides in a WPF form.  Because the checkbox is in a user control that gets added to the form multiple times, I'm unsure how to do this.  I've created a binding for a DevExpress RichEdit control which worked and then modified that code for the checkbox, but it didn't work.

My code to return the binding is as follows:

```
private Binding SetIsCorrectBinding(int row) 
    {
        Binding binding = new Binding("DataModel.DetailList[" + row + "].IsCorrect")
        {
            Path = new PropertyPath("DataModel.DetailList[" + row + "].IsCorrect"),
            Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay
        };
        return binding;
    }
```

The code to implement the binding is as follows:

```
Binding cbBind = SetIsCorrectBinding(row);
detailRow.IsCorrect_cb.SetBinding(CheckBox.ContentProperty, cbBind);
```

No matter what I try, the IsCorrect variable is always false.
Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What you are trying to bind? `true`/`false` seems to mean `bool`, which would typically be bound to `IsChecked`. You are binding to the `Content` property, which affects how the `CheckBox` is displayed...bound to a `bool` type, I would expect the control to display the current `bool` value (e.g. `"False"`), and would not expect the source property to ever be changed (since the `CheckBox` isn't an edit control). It is not clear at all what you're trying to do. Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the next:

```
    var xBinding = new Binding();
    //a real instance of the object where the source property is defined
    //it have to be the same instance which is defined in DataModel.DetailList
    xBinding.Source = sourceInstance;
    xBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("The_source_property_name");
    xBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
    xBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
    //Use this instead the .SetBinding( , ) where the checkbox is the object to binded to
    BindingOperations.SetBinding(checkbox, CheckBox.ContentProperty, xBinding);
```

Please look at the next solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33980902/getting-binding-of-transform-property-from-code-behind/33981587#33981587), I think it can supply an additional information for you. 
I will glad to help if you will have the problem with code.
regards,

Answer (score 0):

6 years late, but I had a similar issue. You need to bind to the Checkbox.IsCheckedProperty

```
detailRow.IsCorrect_cb.SetBinding(CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty, cbBind);
```

was the fix you needed.