# Getting binding of transform property from code behind in ItemsControl

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, code-behind

Xaml as below:

```
<ItemsControl
    x:Class="PowersOf2.Windows10.Views.Controls.Board"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:PowersOf2.Windows10.Views.Controls"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    x:Name="Root" ItemsSource="{Binding Fields, ElementName=Root}" Loaded="Root_Loaded"
>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid
                Width="{Binding FieldWidth, ElementName=Root}"
                Height="{Binding FieldHeight, ElementName=Root}"
                Loaded="Grid_Loaded" Background="White"
            >
                <Grid.RenderTransform>
                    <TranslateTransform X="{Binding X}" Y="{Binding Y}"/>
                </Grid.RenderTransform>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" Foreground="Black"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

`Fields` is `IEnumerable` of `Field` which has coordinates `X` and `Y`. They are managed by view model. `FieldWidth` and `FieldHeight` are dependency properties calculated in code behind.

How to get binding object of nested dependency properties such as `TranslateTransform.X` and `TranslateTransform.Y` in code behind?

### UPDATE:

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051360/in-wpf-how-to-get-binding-of-a-specific-item-from-the-code): Fredrik's answer works as expected until you work with single embedded object in xaml with binding to non-nested properties, but not for nested ones. This issue is more complicated due to `ItemsControl` containing my `Grid`.

Code behind below:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;

namespace Controls
{
    public sealed partial class Board
    {
        public Board()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Root_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            FieldWidth = 100.0;
            FieldHeight = 100.0;
            Fields =
                new Field[]
                {
                    new Field { X = 100, Y = 100, Text = "one" },
                    new Field { X = 300, Y = 300, Text = "two" }
                };
        }

        public double FieldWidth
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(FieldWidthProperty); }
            set { SetValue(FieldWidthProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty FieldWidthProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "FieldWidth", typeof(double), typeof(Board), new PropertyMetadata(0.0)
        );

        public double FieldHeight
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(FieldHeightProperty); }
            set { SetValue(FieldHeightProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty FieldHeightProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "FieldHeight", typeof(double), typeof(Board), new PropertyMetadata(0.0)
        );

        public IEnumerable<Field> Fields
        {
            get { return (ObservableCollection<Field>)GetValue(FieldsProperty); }
            set { SetValue(FieldsProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty FieldsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Fields", typeof(IEnumerable<Field>), typeof(Board), new PropertyMetadata(null)
        );

        private void Grid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // here I want to get binding of RenderTransform's properties
        }
    }

    public class Field : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private int _x;
        public int X
        {
            get { return _x; }
            set
            {
                _x = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("X"));
            }
        }

        private int _y;
        public int Y
        {
            get { return _y; }
            set
            {
                _y = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Y"));
            }
        }

        private string _text;
        public string Text
        {
            get { return _text; }
            set
            {
                _text = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Text"));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
}
```

Comment: What _specifically_ are you having trouble with? Do you not understand how to get the `Grid` for the specific data item? Or is that, having gotten that object, you don't understand how to get the binding for that object's `RenderTransform` object's properties? Please provide a good [mcve] that shows clearly what you've tried, along with a precise explanation of what that code does and how that's different from what you want.

Comment: @Peter Duniho, question updated

Comment: You are asking for help with code-behind, and yet your question does not include any code-behind, never mind is it a complete example. Please provide a better code example if you want help. Please read [mcve] if you have not done so already; re-read it if you have, to make sure you understand what kind of code example is needed.

Comment: @Peter Duniho, I read it and imho it met all requirements. But I don't mind providing this simple method.

Comment: _"it met all requirements"_ -- your post _objectively_ fails to meet the requirements. There's a reason the word "complete" is used in the phrase "Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable example". And it's used not in a wishy-washy "oh, this is 'complete enough'" sort of way; it's used to describe a code example that can be copy/pasted from the web page into the empty source files of an appropriate project and run without any further work.

Comment: @Peter Duniho, question updated

Comment: Seems re-added in Windows 8.1 API as from https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c2c8dbd1-ab06-43b5-859a-c26f9bf740bf/getbinding-alternative

Comment: This still does not solve problem of nested dependency properties inside `ItemsControl`.

Answer (score 3):

I hope I haven't misinterpreted the question but you can get the transformation and the bound item like this.

```
private void Grid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var grid = (Grid)sender;
    //the actual transformation
    var render = (Transform)grid.GetValue(RenderTransformProperty);
    //the field the transformation is bound to
    var field = (Field)grid.DataContext;

    //for now this only works in WPF
    var binding = BindingOperations.GetBinding(render, TranslateTransform.XProperty);
}
```

Made an edit for this, but it does not work for winrt.
The method BindingOperations.GetBinding is only available in WPF.

Hope that winrt gets this soon.

Comment: No. That's not what I meant. I want to get `Binding` object. Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051360/in-wpf-how-to-get-binding-of-a-specific-item-from-the-code. Frederik's answer is exactly what I mean. But this works unless you use nested dependency properties embedded in the list container.

Comment: I hate giving this sort of response, but I'm sure you know that in WPF it's as easy as `var binding = BindingOperations.GetBinding(render, TranslateTransform.XProperty);`.  I haven't been able to find any equivilant to this in winrt...

Comment: Ok, I checked. There is another API in winRT. The signature of something like `GetBinding` is `public BindingExpression GetBindingExpression(DependencyProperty dp)` in `FrameworkElement` class. `Transform` nor `TranslateTransform` have nothing like this. Put complete solution in your answer (including getting bindings) in WPF. It might be helpful.